# How to inject value from AWS parameter store through CloudFormation in ECS ContainerDefinitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-ecs

I'm creating a cloud formation code to build ECS cluster. Where I need to fetch some values from AWS parameter store. I don't find any example code sample for the same. Look like 'ValueFrom' in cloudFormation don't support!!

Can anyone confirm?

Following I'm trying to use:

```
  ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: !Ref ServiceName
      Image: !Ref Image
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
      Environment:
      - Name: DB_HOST
        Value: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:111111111111:parameter/dev/rds/DB_HOST
      - Name: DB_PASSWORD
        Value: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:111111111111:parameter/dev/rds/DB_PASSWORD
      - Name: DB_PORT
        Value: 5432
```

In the above case, CloudFormation codes executed without error but it's treated DB_HOST and DB_PASSWORD as simple/direct text don't take form parameter store, check the screenshot highlighted:

[image]

So it only works for DB_PORT and doesn't work for DB_HOST and DB_PASSWORD until I manually change 'value' (highlighted in the screenshot) to 'valueFrom' like below picture:

[image]

Basically I'd like to use 'valueFrom' option through CloudFormation !!

I also tried:

```
     Environment:
      - Name: DB_HOST
        ValueFrom: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:111111111111:parameter/dev/rds/DB_HOST
```

But it's not supported by cloud formation and through error !!

Comment: Basically, we have to replace "Environment:" with "Secrets:"

Comment: Yeah, I already voted for your Ans, Thanks again @Marcin

Comment: Voting is different then accepting. If you are not accepting correct answers, you question is constantly listed in [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services?tab=Unanswered) queue.

Comment: Just done. thanks to make me aware :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoudn't be using `Environment` for that. Instead there is dedicated section called [Secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-secrets).

Using this section you can [pass your secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html) to the containers. For example:

```
  Secrets:
      - Name: DB_HOST
        ValueFrom: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:111111111111:parameter/dev/rds/DB_HOST
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcin, that is what I was looking for, it works for me !!

Answer (score 0):

After you manually change your Environment variables to ValueFrom, you can checkout your jason file in the TaskDefinition, it shows there as secrets, hence you should use Secrets instead of Environment in the ContainerDefinitions section of your CFT
[Checkout the screenshot I attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPbVr.png)

Comment: Wha does your answer provided that's not already in the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869598/5493813)?

Comment: It shows you the way how to figure out which property name to use by looking into the jason file. Unfortunately, the aws docs are unclear.